# How should I control the state of a class instance property with a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using a third-party library that uses class instances with getter/setter properties, and I'd like to control those properties using a VueJS component.  I'm not supposed to use the instance as component state directly (Evan You says it's "[a rabbit hole](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2718#issuecomment-214003100)"), but if I have to write my own go-between code to map component state to class state, what's the point of reactive data binding in the first place?

Example:

```js
// Toggle.js
var Toggle = Vue.component("Toggle", {
  template: '<label><input type="checkbox" v-model="visible">Click me!</label>',
  props: ["visible"]
});

// Third-party library
var Widget = function() {
  this._visible = true;
}
Widget.prototype = {
  get visible(){ return this._visible; },
  set visible(v){ this._visible = v; }
}

// app.js
var widgets = [new Widget(), new Widget(), new Widget()];
var v = new Vue({
  el: "#content",
  template: "<div><toggle v-for='(widget,idx) in widgets' :visible='widget.visible' :key='idx'></toggle></div>",
  data: {widgets},
  components: { Toggle }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

The above example is not the right way to do this for two reasons: one, because `props` is meant to be a one-way binding from the parent down to the child, and two, because the Widget instance is a complex object that cannot be made reactive.

What's a good design pattern for this case?  Remember, I don't control the Widget class so any solution must work without changing its definition.

Comment: See my updated answer on the original question. I goofed.

Comment: I'd still like some guidance on usage patterns.  I've simplified things a bit above but it maps pretty closely to what I'm trying to accomplish -- the component should an input that binds to a property (defined with getter/setter) of a large, complex object, without having to observe every aspect of that object.  It seems like it should be a common need but I can't find a single tutorial that does this.

Comment: Here is your Widget working.  https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KnFLHckpAl_C53PAvRU

Comment: I commented on the original question, and your example is very helpful, but I do still need a way to avoid observing every aspect of the object -- your linked solution is great but I believe it does result in Vue reacting to any change in `settings`.  For other parts of this project, I need to handle the case where I need to react to a change in one property of a large, complex object that would be expensive to observe. I can think of some workarounds based on your example but they would be hacks; it feels like this is just a part of Vue I don't fully grok.